# Parallel recursive function in R?

Tags: r, recursion, parallel-processing, mclapply

I’ve been wracking my brain around this problem all week and could really use an outside perspective. Basically I’ve built a recursive tree function where the output of each node in one layer is used as the input for a node in the subsequent layer. I’ve generated a toy example here where each call generates a large matrix, splits it into submatrices, and then passes those submatrices to subsequent calls. The key difference from similar questions on Stack is that each call of `tree_search` doesn't actually return anything, it just appends results onto a CSV file.

Now I'd like to parallelize this function. However, when I run it with `mclapply` and `mc.cores=2`, the runtime increases! The same happens when I run it on a multicore cluster with `mc.cores=12`. What’s going on here? Are the parent nodes waiting for the child nodes to return some output? Does this have something to do with fork/socket parallelization?

For background, this is part of an algorithm that models gene activation in white blood cells in response to viral infection. I’m a biologist and self-taught programmer so I’m a little out of my depth here - any help or leads would be really appreciated!

```
# Load libraries.
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

# Recursive tree search function.
tree_search <- function(submx = NA, loop = 0) {

  # Terminate on fifth loop.
  message(paste("Started loop", loop))
  if(loop == 5) {return(TRUE)}

  # Create large matrix and do some operation.
  bigmx <- matrix(rnorm(10), 50000, 250)
  bigmx <- sin(bigmx^2)

  # Aggregate matrix and save output.
  agg <- colMeans(bigmx)
  append <- file.exists("output.csv")
  fwrite(t(agg), file = "output.csv", append = append, row.names = F)

  # Split matrix in submatrices with 100 columns each.
  ind <- ceiling(seq_along(1:ncol(bigmx)) / 100)

  lapply(unique(ind), function(i) {

    submx <- bigmx[, ind == i]

    # Pass each submatrix to subsequent call.
    loop <- loop + 1
    tree_search(submx, loop) # sub matrix is used to generate big matrix in subsequent call (not shown)

  })

}

# Initiate tree search.
tree_search()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more brain wracking and experimentation, I ended up answering my own question. I’m not going to refer to the original example since I've changed up my approach quite a bit. Instead I’ll share some general observations that might help people in similar situations.

**1.) `For` loops are more memory efficient than `lapply` and recursive functions**

When you use lapply, each call creates a copy of your current environment. That’s why you can do this:

```
x <- 5
lapply(1:10, function(i) {
   x <- x + 1
   x == 6 # TRUE
})
x == 5 # ALSO TRUE
```

At the end x is still 5, which means that each call of `lapply` was manipulating a separate copy of x. That’s not good if, say, x was actually a large dataframe with 10,000 variables. `for` loops, on the other hand, allow you to override the variables on each loop.

```
x <- 5
for(i in 1:10) {x <- x + 1}
x == 5 # FALSE
```

**2.) Parallelize once**

Distributing tasks to different nodes takes a lot of computational overhead and can cancel out any gains you make from parallelizing your script. Therefore, you should use `mclapply` with discretion. In my case, that meant NOT putting `mclapply` inside a recursive function where it was getting called tens to hundreds of times. Instead, I split the starting point into 16 parts and ran 16 different tree searches on separate nodes.

**3.) You can use `mclapply` to throttle memory usage**

If you split a job into 10 parts and process them with `mclapply` and `mc.preschedule=F`, each core will only process 10% of your job at a time. If `mc.cores` was set to two, for example, the other 8 "nodes" would wait until one part finished before starting a new one. This is useful if you are running into memory issues and want to prevent each loop from taking on more than it can handle.

**Final Note**

This is one of the more interesting problems I’ve worked on so far. However, recursive tree functions are complicated. Draw out the algorithm and force yourself to spend a few days away from your code so that you can come back with a fresh perspective.